# How many arrangements we can make from the word "SINGAPORE" where the letters $E$ and $I$ do not occur together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutations

Find the number of arrangements for the letters in `SINGAPORE` given that `I` and `E` must be separated by at least one letter.

My answer:

`S N G A P O R` ${}\implies 7!$ ways to arrange

There are $8$ spaces between `S N G A P O R`
so $\binom{8}{2} \cdot 2!$ ways to slot the `I` and `E`.

Therefore, $\binom{8}{2} \cdot 2! \cdot 7! = 282\,240$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yep.  Looks right.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You can take all the possibilities and subtract the cases where the letters $E$ and $I$ occur together.

Hence the desired result can be expressed as $9! - 2\times 8! = 282240$. Thus your answer is correct.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Joe You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at the problem (and thus a way to check the answer) is:

- There are 9! permutations of `SINGAPORE` (since all the letters are distinct).
- There are 8! permutations of `SINGAPORE` where `I` comes immediately after `E` (we permute `SNGAPORE` then add `I` after `E`).
- There are 8! permutations of `SINGAPORE` where `I` comes immediately before `E` (we permute `SNGAPORE` then add `I` before `E`).

So there are $9!-2 \times 8! = 282240$ possibilities.